# check duplication using mysql select

Tags: mysql

I have a category say ecommerce.add ebay and amazon.when i update ebay as amazon,it should n't update.How do i d it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check  out unique indexes and primary keys. These will cause an insert or update to fail rather that allow duplicate entries to be made.

Comment: You need to catch any error on the server, (you don't say  what language you are using), then if there is an error, you handle it in an appropriate manner eg direct the user to an error page and ask tehm for a different name or suggest a unique version of the one they entered. Trying to check uniqueness with select will be prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_unique ON tablename (name(10));
```

Replace `name_unique` with the name you want for the index, `tablename` with the name of your table, and `name(10)` with the column name and how many characters you want to be unique (the length of the column if you want the entire value to be unique).

Comment: no indexes is going to solve my problem.while,i add using select if this is there pop up and error msg.how do i do it in update.